# Backbonejs setter returns undefined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am using Backbone.Mutators.js js plugin to override setter and getter. Below is my Model

```
var BuyerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    mutators: {
        fullName: {
            get: function () {
                return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Below is how I am setting and getting full name.

```
    var buyerModel = new BuyerModel();

    buyerModel.set({ firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Bloggs' });

    console.log(buyerModel.get('fullName')); // returns undefined undefined
    console.log(buyerModel.get('firstName')); // return Joe
    console.log(buyerModel.get('lastName')); // returns Bloggs
```

**Why fullName returns undefined undefined and how to fix it?**

Comment: is there any errors in console? set breakpoint to your mutator get method and check is it called and that contained in `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the mutators plugin but it would appear you need to change your function to

```
return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
```

This means the the scope of the function is the the model not the attributes sub object.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes of the model is stored in it's `attributes` property, those are not direct properties of the instance, you should use the `get` method:

```
return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
```